# Это приложение не совместимо с последней версией Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle, совместимость

Так и не нашёл информации. После обновления до Android 14 в приложении при первом запуске вылезает диалог "Это приложение не совместимо с последней версией Android. Проверьте наличие обновлений или свяжитесь с разработчиком приложения." При этом приложение работает без проблем.
[image: вот это окно]

Все зависимости и библиотеки обновлены до последних версий, compileSdk/targetSdk стоят 34. Не понимаю как оно может быть несовместимо. Есть какие-то дополнительные нюансы?

Comment: Если вы ничего не путаете, то я могу предположить лишь один вариант: в новую версию добавлены какие-то uses-feature которых нет на этом устройстве из-за чего приложение не обновляется и продолжает работать на старой версии.

Comment: я ничего не путаю и приложение обновляется. если устанавливать с нуля, тоже устанавливается.. 
uses-feature которые используются у меня: 
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

Comment: я так понял, никто не знает ответа на этот вопрос...

Comment: @Style-7, тогда бы писало что несовместимо с устройством. А тут очень похоже какая-то новинка в Андроид 14. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77818852/5479247

Comment: тогда, похоже это баг андроида